# Hive SQL query, how do i filter based on integer value in a map?

Tags: sql, dictionary, hive, hiveql

I have a column that has a value looks like this. It's in a map(varchar, integer) format.

`{Retail/Mass Retail=1, Restaurant=1, Beverage - Alcohol=2, Entertainment=1, CPG - Consumer Packaged Goods=2, Pharmaceutical=2}`

How can I only select the rows where "Retail/Mass Retail" value is over 1 in Hive SQL? I don't know what would go after the `where` clause:

```
select * table name where ________
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you create sample code/data and paste it here so that I can understand the data structure of your input column? Also, let me know on how many rows you have in the table, because `explode` is an option that we can pursue.

Comment: hi! i didn't create this table. but let's say name of this column is `impression` and this is one sample value for a row. it's a map

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command

```
select * table name where col['Retail/Mass Retail'] > 1
```